# Query on-prem SQL Server and Azure SQL server with one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, ssis

I have an SSIS package that moves data from disparate sources to an on premises staging table where I run some T-SQL commands on the data. I'm trying to push this data to Azure but my query is being non-responsive. My data structure looks like this:

```
Source    Data
  |        |
  |        |
  ----------
  Merge Join
  ----------
      |
      |
  ----------
   Staging
  ----------
      |
      |    
  ----------
    Azure
  ----------
```

The staging SQL server contains two tables. One is supposed to be a mirror of what will be in the final Azure table for backup purposes. The second is a temporary table that is created via the `FULL OUTER JOIN` inside of the  `Merge Join` which I use to compare source data and destination data and `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` the mirror table based on whether an item in the source is `NULL` `(INSERT)` or if an item is in both `(UPDATE)` etc. Everything works on my end as I want it to.

Here is the query that is performing the above `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`:

```
--INSERT
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO
    dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL (
      [SubtaskID],
      [Supplier],
      [Level],
      [Status],
      [Core Competency Service Provided],
      [Location],
      [Outsourced Process],
      [Contact],
      [Phone],
      [Email]
    )
  SELECT
    [SubtaskID],
    [Supplier],
    [Level],
    [Status],
    [Core Competency Service Provided],
    [Location],
    [Outsourced Process],
    [Contact],
    [Phone],
    [Email]
  FROM
    dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP
  WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1
      FROM dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL
      WHERE dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL.SubtaskID = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.SubtaskID
    )
END
--UPDATE
BEGIN
  UPDATE
    dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL
  SET
    dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL.Supplier = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Supplier,
    dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL.Level = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Level,
    dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL.Status = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Status,
    dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL.[Core Competency Service Provided] = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.[Core Competency Service Provided],
    dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL.Location = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Location,
    dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL.[Outsourced Process] = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.[Outsourced Process],
    dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL.Contact = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Contact,
    dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL.Phone = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Phone,
    dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL.Email = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Email
  FROM
    dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL
    INNER JOIN dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP
      ON dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL.SubtaskID = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.SubtaskID
  WHERE
    dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL.SubtaskID = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.SubtaskID
    AND dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL.SubtaskID IS NOT NULL AND dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.SubtaskID IS NOT NULL
END
--DELETE
BEGIN
  DELETE
  FROM dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL
  WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT *
      FROM dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP
      WHERE dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL.SubtaskID = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.SubtaskID
    )
END
```

I'm trying to perform the same action on the Azure SQL server but it is not working. Both of these queries are running on my on premises server but the Azure server is a linked server. I should be able to query it like this no?

```
--INSERT
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO
    [AZURE_REPORTING].[Reporting_Warehouse].[dbo].[SupplierQuality_ASL] (
      [SubtaskID],
      [Supplier],
      [Level],
      [Status],
      [Core Competency Service Provided],
      [Location],
      [Outsourced Process],
      [Contact],
      [Phone],
      [Email]
    )
  SELECT
    [SubtaskID],
    [Supplier],
    [Level],
    [Status],
    [Core Competency Service Provided],
    [Location],
    [Outsourced Process],
    [Contact],
    [Phone],
    [Email]
  FROM
    dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP
  WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1
      FROM dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL
      WHERE dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL.SubtaskID = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.[SubtaskID (1)]
    )
END
--UPDATE
BEGIN
  UPDATE
    [AZURE_REPORTING].[Reporting_Warehouse].[dbo].[SupplierQuality_ASL]
  SET
    [AZURE_REPORTING].[Reporting_Warehouse].[dbo].[SupplierQuality_ASL].Supplier = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Supplier,
    [AZURE_REPORTING].[Reporting_Warehouse].[dbo].[SupplierQuality_ASL].Level = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Level,
    [AZURE_REPORTING].[Reporting_Warehouse].[dbo].[SupplierQuality_ASL].Status = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Status,
    [AZURE_REPORTING].[Reporting_Warehouse].[dbo].[SupplierQuality_ASL].[Core Competency Service Provided] = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.[Core Competency Service Provided],
    [AZURE_REPORTING].[Reporting_Warehouse].[dbo].[SupplierQuality_ASL].Location = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Location,
    [AZURE_REPORTING].[Reporting_Warehouse].[dbo].[SupplierQuality_ASL].[Outsourced Process] = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.[Outsourced Process],
    [AZURE_REPORTING].[Reporting_Warehouse].[dbo].[SupplierQuality_ASL].Contact = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Contact,
    [AZURE_REPORTING].[Reporting_Warehouse].[dbo].[SupplierQuality_ASL].Phone = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Phone,
    [AZURE_REPORTING].[Reporting_Warehouse].[dbo].[SupplierQuality_ASL].Email = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Email
  FROM
    dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL
    INNER JOIN dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP
      ON dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL.SubtaskID = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.SubtaskID
  WHERE
    dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL.SubtaskID = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.SubtaskID
    AND dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL.SubtaskID IS NOT NULL AND dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.SubtaskID IS NOT NULL
END
--DELETE
BEGIN
  DELETE
  FROM [AZURE_REPORTING].[Reporting_Warehouse].[dbo].[SupplierQuality_ASL]
  WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT *
      FROM dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP
      WHERE dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL.SubtaskID = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.SubtaskID
    )
END
```

This isn't working however, when I run my package nothing gets populated in the Azure DB. I know it should work because the server is linked unless I have a syntax error. I've triple verified my naming is correct, what would prevent this from working?

Comment: I would think of that temp table creation issue in Azure, add try/Catch blocks you will know whats causing the issue.

Comment: You might get better answers on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Cheers ok I might repost this over there if I keep hitting the same wall.